# method_missing when `rake test` loads a model, although it loads correctly if Rails does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rake, undefined

Well, I have acts_as_taggable_on installed, and it is loaded in one of my models.
Although when loading Rails it works correctly and without errors, when it is loaded to do a `rake test` it throws me an `method_missing: undefined method acts_as_taggable_on for ...`

I read that it might be a environment related issue, but I couldn't find any other info =/

Comment: Where did you include the gem? in development.rb ? Or in Gemfile?

Comment: Are you including the gem only in development group?

Comment: @Arun So THAT'S what groups are for! haha, thanks.
Add the answer so I select it as the former accepted answer haha

Comment: Good that you have solved the issue :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have added the gem in development group.

To understand about groups in Gemfile - http://gembundler.com/groups.html